# Convert Class from single Js web page to ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react, and I'm working on a small project that uses a search bar in Single js Web page to find data from API.

The main code for this component is:

```
const main = () => {
const searchElement = document.querySelector("search-bar");
const clubListElement = document.querySelector("club-list");
const onButtonSearchClicked = async() => {
    try{
        const result = await DataSource.searchClub(searchElement.value);
        renderResult(result);
    } catch (message) {
        fallbackResult(message)
    }
};

const renderResult = (results) => {
    clubListElement.clubs = results;
        };

const fallbackResult = message => {
    clubListElement.renderError(message);     
};
searchElement.clickEvent = onButtonSearchClicked;
};

export default main;
```

also my Search-Bar component:

```
    class SearchBar extends HTMLElement{

   constructor(){
      super();
      this.shadowDOM = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
   }

   connectedCallback(){
      this.render();
   }

   set clickEvent(event){
      this._clickEvent = event;
      this.render();
   }

   get value(){
      //return this.querySelector("#searchElement").value;
      return this.shadowDOM.querySelector("#searchElement").value;
   }

   render(){
      //this.innerHTML = `
      this.shadowDOM.innerHTML = `
      <style>
      .search-container {
         max-width: 800px;
         box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
         padding: 16px;
         border-radius: 5px;
         display: flex;
         position: sticky;
         top: 10px;
         background-color: white;
     }

     .search-container > input {
         width: 75%;
         padding: 16px;
         border: 0;
         border-bottom: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
         font-weight: bold;
     }

     .search-container > input:focus {
         outline: 0;
         border-bottom: 2px solid cornflowerblue;
     }

     .search-container > input:focus::placeholder {
         font-weight: bold;
     }

     .search-container >  input::placeholder {
         color: cornflowerblue;
         font-weight: normal;
     }

     .search-container > button {
         width: 23%;
         cursor: pointer;
         margin-left: auto;
         padding: 16px;
         background-color: cornflowerblue;
         color: white;
         border: 0;
         text-transform: uppercase;
     }

     @media screen and (max-width: 550px){
         .search-container {
             flex-direction: column;
             position: static;
         }

         .search-container > input {
             width: 100%;
             margin-bottom: 12px;
         }

         .search-container > button {
             width: 100%;
         }
     }
      </style>
      <div id="search-container" class="search-container">
         <input placeholder="Search football club" id="searchElement" type="search">
         <button id="searchButtonElement" type="submit">Search</button>
      </div>
      `;

      this.shadowDOM.querySelector("#searchButtonElement").addEventListener("click", this._clickEvent);
   }
}

customElements.define("search-bar", SearchBar);
```

furthermore, can i convert this method to ReactJS? because we know if we can't declare a const in render() from React.

I have been through a bunch of flustered, and I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing that.

Can anyone help me with this please? Any other comments on the code are also welcome because i'm new in Reacts

Thank you before!

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you should remove all that CSS declaration within the `render` method, and abstract them into a separate CSS file (you can consider [CSS modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/), which is supported by React), use CSS-in-JavaScript libraries(such as [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/)), or [inline styles](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style).

Next, instead of using event listeners, you should bind the `button` element's onClick event with the `onButtonSearchClicked` method, which is similar to what you have defined.

From that method, you will make the API request, and update your component's [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html) with the response.

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {

  async onButtonSearchClicked() {
    const result = await DataSource.searchClub(searchElement.value);
    // set state with return result.
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="search-container" class="search-container">
        <input placeholder="Search football club" id="searchElement" type="search">
        <button id="searchButtonElement" type="submit" onClick={() => this.onButtonSearchClicked}>Search</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of many variants how could `SearchBar` component look like in React

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    this.ref = React.createRef(null);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.shadowDOM = this.ref.current.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
    this.shadowDOM.innerHTML = getStyle();
  }

  onClick(event) {

  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.ref} id="search-container" class="search-container">
         <input placeholder="Search football club" id="searchElement" type="search">
         <button onClick={this.onClick} id="searchButtonElement" 
  type="submit">Search</button>
      </div>
  }
```